# Redirect to /amp page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, amp-html

When the user accesses the `http://examle.com/review/amp/tes1/test2`, it should redirect to `http://examle.com/review/amp`

In the WordPress redirect module, I have given below regex

**Source**: `/review/amp/(.*)$`

**Target**: `/review/amp`

But this throws `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` issue.

Is there any way to fix this issue

Comment: Use `Source: /review/amp/(.+)$`

Comment: @anubhava That works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any plugin?
If you can provide which plugin, I can let you know what will work in that plugin.

But in general, you can also do it with .htaccess with following rule

```
RewriteRule ^review/amp/.+ review/amp [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Using WordPress redirection plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). However, the solution given in the comment fixes the issue.